# Solving two equations in three variables

Tags: vectors, systems-of-equations, inner-products, solid-geometry

A solution to the system of equations

> $ax + by +cz = 0$
>
> $a^2x+b^2y+c^2z=0$ is
>
> Ans: $x=\frac{k (b-c)}{a}$   $y= \frac{k (c-a)}{b}$     $z=\frac{k (a-b)}
> {c}$ where $k$ is an arbitrary constant.

A system of two equations in three variables is supposed to given an equation that in one independent variable. How do I reconcile this fact to the given solution and how do I reach this solution ?

Comment: The independent variable is taken to be $k$, to obtain similar formulæ for $x,y,z$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are equations of two planes and we need to find an equation of the common line of these planes.

Thus, with assumption that they are not parallel  planes we need to prove that
$$(a,b,c)\perp\left(\frac{b-c}{a},\frac{c-a}{b},\frac{a-b}{c}\right),$$ which is $$a\cdot\frac{b-c}{a}+b\cdot\frac{c-a}{b}+c\cdot\frac{a-b}{c}=0$$ and
$$(a^2,b^2,c^2)\perp\left(\frac{b-c}{a},\frac{c-a}{b},\frac{a-b}{c}\right),$$which is
$$a^2\cdot\frac{b-c}{a}+b^2\cdot\frac{c-a}{b}+c^2\cdot\frac{a-b}{c}=0,$$ 
which is obvious.

Comment: Could you please tell me how we arrive at the two equations , I'm still refreshing my math on planes

Comment: I added something. See now.

Comment: Thanks a lot Michael Rozenberg

Comment: You are welcome!

Answer (score 1):

solve your first equation for $z$ then we get
$$z=-\frac{a}{c}x-\frac{b}{c}y$$ plugging this in your second equation we obtain
$$a^2x+b^2y+c^2\left(-\frac{a}{c}x-\frac{b}{c}y\right)=0$$
solve this for $x$ and set $$y=k$$
simplifying the equation above we obtain
$$x(a^2-ac)=(bc-b^2)y$$
so $$x=\frac{(bc-b^2)y}{a^2-ac}$$ if $$a^2-ac\neq 0$$
with $$y=k$$ we have
$$z=-\frac{a}{c}\left(\frac{(bc-b^2)y}{a^2-ac}\right)-\frac{b}{c}y$$
we Can write $$\left\{ x={\frac {cz \left( -c+b \right) }{ \left( a-b \right) a}},y=
-{\frac {c \left( a-c \right) z}{b \left( a-b \right) }},z=z \right\} 
$$

Comment: Could you please show the working so that I can understand better, thanks.